# Why does an sql query return nothing if I don't pass the range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is my query

```sql
IF (@GLAccountNo IS NULL OR @GLAccountNo = '')
BEGIN
    IF (@GLAccountNoFrom IS NULL OR @GLAccountNoFrom = '')
    BEGIN
        SET @TempGLAccountNo = 10000000000;
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @TempGLAccountNo = @GLAccountNoFrom;
    END;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @TempGLAccountNo = @GLAccountNo;
END;


SELECT *
FROM GLedger G
WHERE ((G.GLAccountNo >= @TempGLAccountNoFrom)
   AND (G.GLAccountNo <= @TempGLAccountNo));
```

whereas
`@TempGLAccountNoFrom` and `@TempGLAccountNo` are like these

**432000000** and **433000000** etc.

It works but if don't pass then it doesn't work and returns nothing.

How do I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by if you "don't pass"? As in the values of the variables/parameters are `NULL`? If so, because *nothing* equals `NULL`, including `NULL`.

Comment: *Now* (based on your latest edit) I would guess it's because no rows have a value of `10000000000` for `GLAccountNo`. Sample data, and expected results, will help us help you. Are you actually after a catch-all/kitchen sink query?

Comment: It looks like you're handling `@TempGLAccountNo` but there could be cases when you're not assigning a value for `@TempGLAccountNoFrom`.

Comment: Indenting your code, when inside things like `IF` operators is also really important in my opinion; if makes nothing what is inside each of them so much easier. YOu should really get into the habit of making good use of both line breaks and white space.

Answer (score 0):

if @TempGLAccountNoFrom and @TempGLAccountNo can be null, then you can conditionally add the range query like

```
select * from GLedger G
where 
((@TempGLAccountNoFrom is null or G.GLAccountNo >= @TempGLAccountNoFrom) AND (@TempGLAccountNo is null or G.GLAccountNo <= @TempGLAccountNo))
```

Comment: With logic like this, I strongly recommend adding `RECOMPILE` to the `OPTION` clause of the query. Otherwise this could very easily/quickly suffer from poor plan caching.